# How do I solve these errors in Kinect

Tags: kinect

I have some problems with my Kinect.

1. The green light is flashing.
2. From time to time, I hear the disconnect and connect sound from my laptop.
   (It is new -- close to 3 months old).
3. I run the Kinect Studio v2.0 and I get a gray screen.

It is a Kinect model 1517.

Comment: Some discussion here....https://forum.ni-mate.com/t/kinect-model-1517-windows-10-problems-getting-it-to-work/1604

Comment: What diagnosis have you run so far? What has your own research indicated?

Comment: I though it may be something with the battery so i let it to charge but it did not work(I dont know if it is that i run it on win10)(or i am using kinect studio v2.0)

Comment: The usb ports work fine but it stil disconnect and re-connect